# Can't play video in browser

Tags: video, browser

Lately video clips wont play in browser: both Chromium & Firefox.
The Ubuntu version is 18.04.5 LTS, running on a virtual machine over Windows 10 host.

The video clip is played in the small preview window of the browser (for example in YouTube after search) when the mouse hoovers over the small window, but when this video is selected and clicked, it is opened, yet it is freezing and not play.

I tried some guidance from Firefox (remove HW acceleration), but I guess the problem is somehow with the OS, because Chromium stopped playing videos as well.

Another parallel problem which I am not sure if it is related, is with the upgrade (I opened another thread) - the Ubuntu 18 keeps being updated but when I try upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 - it starts and crash. Also with command line.
I see no direct connection between these two issues, yet they may be related.

Additional info since I posted the question: the later part about Ubuntu upgrade was solved, simply after Oracle released a new VM version. I would assume they had a bug that is now fixed.
Still, now with the new installed Ubuntu 20.04 the original bug still exists: browsers will not play Videos. Since both Firefix and Chrome have same issue, I would assume the problem is somehow still related to the VM machine or to the Ubuntu OS. I am still investigating it.

Comment: @guiverc The release was updated in the question. The version used is  18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for the original problem (no video on browser) and later (Ubuntu upgrade fail) on my Oracle VM running Ubuntu:
1- No video on browser: After trying all video configurations, it occurred to me that Audio is also part of the system. I change the Audio controller in the VM settings to SoundBLaster and the problem was solved.
2- Ubuntu upgrade fail from 18 to 20: the new release of Oracle VM solved the problem. Probably Oracle's bug was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and have the same issue. In my case, the cause of the issue was Bluetooth headset. Help only changing the output device or reboot.

Comment: This. My case is same. But I don't need reboot my device. Just turn bluetooth speak off, then it worked. Turn on speaker to connect to my pc successully also worked.